# decode a partially encrypted file C#

Tags: encryption

I have a file that is partially encrypted. I can read some of the text but most of them are funny charactors. For example "JD819-Toyota         CAFS        R š™™™™2@)\Âõ(3@ þÿþÿþÿþÿþÿ"
I can read the JD819-Toyota CAFS  but the rest doesn't make any sense. Can someone please point to how I can find ways to read this file? thanks

Below is what I think to be in HEX format. Not sure if I converted correctly

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

Comment: Just because you can't read it doesn't mean it is encrypted. Not all files are text - it could be protobuf or any other non-text serialization format, for example - or it could be compressed. Posting the *bytes* (as hex, ideally) would be far more useful. We might be able to recognize protocol features.

Comment: Agree:  if you find that you can "partially" read it, then this is a dead giveaway that it **is** ***not(!)*** actually "encrypted!"  Instead, it is somehow *"encoded."*  A very, very different thing.

Comment: If it is encoded. How do I decoded? lol

Comment: How would we know? It's probably binary encoded numbers. And where's the hex?

Comment: @user3690095 re decoding it: it *could* be using a common well-known data encoding - we can't even begin to speculate without seeing the hex - but: it could be something that was made up "on the spot" by whoever wrote the code that needed to store a file on disk. If you post the hex we might be able to recognise features, but honestly the best way to answer this question is by referring to the specification (if is is documented), or asking someone that knows what the data format might be

Comment: Just to be clear: the reason we're asking about the hex is that if a file *isn't* text, then reading it via something like notepad *can't show you the real contents* - lots of non-printable data will be lost, and other data will be misinterpreted in ways that makes it impossible to talk about; we'd need to see the actual bytes, and since this is a text-based site, hex is the easiest way to convey bytes without losing data

Comment: It's possible it's not encode or encrypted at all.  It may just be the memory image of the data.   Some looks like simple ascii characters.  Some is zeroes.

Comment: I've given it an eyeball; nothing leaps out as immediately obvious (and I'd have recognised a few). This gives you two immediate options: 1) reverse engineer it manually using multiple files, or 2) ask whoever it came from for the layout